# Configuring the node-exporter in a TiDB cluster deployment via TiUP

Tags: tidb

According to https://docs.pingcap.com/tidb/stable/deploy-monitoring-services during the deployment of a TiDB cluster using TiUP, the monitoring and alert services are automatically deployed, and no manual deployment is needed.

This seems to be true as well for the [Node-Exporter](https://github.com/prometheus/node_exporter) which can be configured in the topology.yml for cluster deployment as described in https://docs.pingcap.com/tidb/stable/tiup-cluster-topology-reference#monitored

Essentially, what can be configured is the port at which the node-exporter exposes its metrics.

On other instances I use the node-exporter as well and use its feature to collect metrics from a local textfile via the `--collector.textfile.directory` flag. I would like to do the same on the TiDB instances.

What I would like to configure is either

1. To add the textfile collector flag with directory to the built-in node-exporter or
2. to prevent TiUP from installing or running the node-exporter (in order to install my own node-exporter)

Is this kind of configuration possible? Or is there any other solution?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the configuration is limited to changing the port at which the node exporter expose its metrics as the following code from TiUP for starting the node-exporter confirms

https://github.com/pingcap/tiup/blob/master/embed/templates/scripts/run_node_exporter.sh.tpl